# NSWindow, press key ENTER: how to limit the key listening to the focused NSControl?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have an `NSWindow` with a main "OK" button. This button has as "key equivalent" property in interface builder, the key <kbd>ENTER</kbd> i.e <kbd>↵</kbd>.

It works good, but now I have a new `NSComboBox`, which is supposed to invoke a method when the user selects a list item, or he preses <kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd>↵</kbd>.

However, when I press Enter, the main Button receive the notification and the window close. How to prevent this?

Comment: Hey I think you have had bounty for this one, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the normal behavior what you are getting, but you can hack a bit, by removing and adding the key-equivalent.

Add following delegates of NSComboBox:

```
- (void)comboBoxWillPopUp:(NSNotification *)notification;{
    [self.closeButton setKeyEquivalent:@""];
}


- (void)comboBoxWillDismiss:(NSNotification *)notification;{
    [self.closeButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];
}
```

Comment: I see, this could be a solution, thanks. The only thing I don't like is that I need to add those lines for every widget I add to my view... if I need to use Enter key on it.

Comment: So you can choose any other key, but in Mac OS X apps, you rarely have much of Keyboard shortcuts, isn't it? Or still you can ask users to use `tab` to select.

Comment: I have at least 2 situations in which I'm sure users will spontaneously press Enter: after typing a new value in the combobox, and after editing a NSTableView cell. Basically, everytime they type something, it is very likely they will press Enter to submit the value.

Comment: In some cases, remove Enter from from Submit. And make it only clickable, and add Cmd+Enter as shortcut. you should, then, show tooltip for that.

Comment: This is a good answer. Since these are delegate methods, you specifically won't have to add "those lines for every widget I add to my view", just connect all those combo boxes to the same delegate. You could probably also subclass NSComboBox and override keyEquivalent, but Apple gives you the delegate option so you don't have to subclass. And you are still going to have to make the class change on all your combo boxes which isn't any easier than giving them delegates. You aren't going to find an easier solution than this one.

Comment: @harrisg Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work. The delegate method are correctly invoked, and the key equivalent is disabled, but it seems that the it is enabled back too early. Probably even if the dropdown list is dismissed the combobox still has focus. Result: the key equivalent is detect to close the screen.

Comment: ok I've found a solution with a small delay. Changed last line to [self.closeButton performSelector:@selector(setKeyEquivalent:) withObject:@"\r" afterDelay:0.01];

Comment: @Patrick: This is indeed the same thing that I used in `comboBoxWillDismiss:` as `[self.closeButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];`

Comment: Yes the method is correct, but it works only if you add that small delay.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can workaround for prevent enter notification is like that below:-

//Connect this action method to your combobbox and inside that set one `BOOL` flag to yes

```
- (IBAction)comBoxItm:(id)sender
{
    self.isEnterCalled=YES;
}
```

//Now check this flag to your some method where close window is called

```
-(void)someMethod
{
//Check the flag value if it is yes then just ignore it
if (!self.isEnterCalled)
{
//Close window logic
}
self.isEnterCalled=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. Had "hot key" which I'd like to switch off while editing some text fields. I found solution for myself. There's no need in override lots of `NSTextField` base methods.

Firstly, I removed all the "key equivalents". I used to detect <kbd>Enter</kbd> key down with the `+ (void)addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(NSEvent *(^)(NSEvent *))block` class method of `NSEvent`. You pass block as a parameter, where you can check for some conditions. The first parameter is the event mask. For your task it would be `NSKeyDownMask`, look for other masks at the [NSEvent Reference Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSEventMaskFromType)

The parameter block will perform each time the user pushes the button. You should check if it is right button pushed, and - generally - if the current window first responder isn't some editable control. For that purposes we need `NSWindow` category class just not to implement this code each time we deal with `NSKeyDownMask`ed local monitors.

`NSWindow+Responders` class listing:

```
@interface NSWindow (Responders)

- (BOOL)isEditableFirstResponder;

@end

@implementation NSWindow (Responders)

- (BOOL)isEditableFirstResponder
{
  if (!self.firstResponder)
    return NO; // no first responder at all
  if ([self.firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]]) // NSComboBox is NSTextField subclass
    {
      NSTextField *field=(NSTextField *)self.firstResponder;
      return field.isEditable;
    }
  if ([self.firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) // yep, buttons may be responders
    return YES;
  return NO; // the first responder is not NSTextField or NSButton subclass - not editable
}

@end
```

Don't know if there's another way to check if we are now editing some text field or combo box. So, there's at least the part you add the local monitor somewhere in your class (NSWindow, NSView, some controller etc.).

```
- (void)someMethod
{
  id monitor=[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:(NSEvent *)^(NSEvent *theEvent){
    if (theEvent.keyCode==/*Enter key code*/ && ![self.window.isEditableFirstResponder]) // you should check the key modifiers too
    {
      // your code here
    }
    return theEvent; // you may return the event to pass the key to the receiver
  }];
}
```

Local monitors is safe remedy about the Apple rules. It works only inside your application. For global key down events you may use `addGlobalMonitor` but Apple may reject your app from the AppStore.

And don't forget to remove the monitor when there's no need in it.

```
- (void)viewControllerShutdownMethod
{
  [NSEvent removeMonitor:monitor];
}
```

Good luck.